# how to parse xml nodes with name attributes

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<sizes>
<size name="original" width="386" height="429">
http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/62380831/Adele+PNG.png
</size>
<size name="large" width="126" height="140">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/62380831.png</size>
<size name="largesquare" width="126" height="126">
http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126s/62380831.png
</size>
<size name="medium" width="64" height="71">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/62380831.png</size>
<size name="small" width="34" height="38">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/62380831.png</size>
<size name="extralarge" width="252" height="280">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/62380831.png</size>
</sizes>
```

How would I get it to parse only the size node with the name `"small"`?

So far I have the code:

```
echo $xml->images->image->sizes->size;
```

which works but it takes the first image, and I want to specifically locate the small image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the small image always be the fifth one? If so, you could use

```
$xml->images->image->sizes->size[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$xml->images->image->sizes->size['name']` ...should work good for getting any of them. No matter how you do it, you'll want to watch out for the fact that **the attribute is an object** and in your situation you probably want it to be a string. Which means you'll need to convert it to a string from an object, and you can do that with the `(string)`, like this:

```
foreach ($xml->size as $size) {
    $the_size = (string) size['name'];
    print $the_size . "<br>";
}
```

That gets all of them & turns them into strings, so you can use string functions like `strstr()` or `strcmp()`.